# How do I draw edge labels for MultiGraph in NetworkX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

In the [class `networkx.MultiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/multigraph.html), an edge is keyed by **`(u, v, key)`**, for instance, `('n1', 'n2', 'key1')`. I would like to draw edge labels (say weight, `(u, v, key): 10`) for `MultiGraph` by using the [function `networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html).

However, edge labels are keyed by a two-tuple `(u, v)` in `draw_networkx_edge_labels`, instead of a **3-tuple** `(u, v, key)`, as is the case in `MultiGraph`. This raises `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

---

PS: The parameter `edge_labels` in `draw_networkx_edge_labels` is described as follows:

```py
draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    G, pos,
    edge_labels=None, label_pos=0.5,
    font_size=10, font_color='k',
    font_family='sans-serif', font_weight='normal',
    alpha=1.0, bbox=None, ax=None,
    rotate=True, **kwds)
```

> Edge labels in a dictionary of labels keyed by edge two-tuple. Only labels for the keys in the dictionary are drawn.

(Note the "two-tuple" in this description.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not even find how to draw a multigraph with `matplotlib` (because the multiple edges won't show up). However if you export to `dot` you will be able to see multiple edges, and you can label them with a label attribute in the edges.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')
G.add_edge('A','B', label='foo')
G.add_edge('A','B', label='bar')
# dump dot code
nx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(G, 'multi.dot')
```

This code requires [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), [`pydot`](https://pypi.org/project/pydot), and [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org).

[image: multigraph with edge labels]

Note that if you look into the module [`networkx.drawing.nx_pylab`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/005e1f9c40056d0da94066953e51991a4d222487/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py), the default behavior of the function [`draw_networkx_edge_labels`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/005e1f9c40056d0da94066953e51991a4d222487/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L930) is [to use](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/005e1f9c40056d0da94066953e51991a4d222487/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L1026)

```py
{(u, v): d for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)}
```

as the (default value for the) `edge_labels` attribute which will fail for multigraphs because the dictionnary key has to be unique. Thus, if you want to plot using `matplotlib`, you will probably need to modify the function `draw_networkx_edge_labels`.